# Can an app manipulate the cellular radio chip?

Tags: cellular-radio, network-signal, radio-firmware

I have a few ideas for a couple local cell to cell apps, but want to use the radio signals to extend the range (the extra work is fine with me).

Just curious if it is possible to control the transmission and receiving of bits. If so, any good docs on it?

Comment: Android does not have any direct access to the radio chip. It only uses the Radio Interface Layer (RIL) which sends all commands to the radio subsystem which can be seen as separate OS inside your phone loaded as blob. Manipulation of the radio subsystem is possible with root permissions, just be aware that any changes usually have legal consequences, hence you should only do so while you are sitting a faraday cage preventing any signal to leave the cage.

Comment: Interesting, thank you @Robert! Do you by chance know of any diagrams or anything that illustrates that dual OS architecture a little better . . . Purely for educational purposes? 

Comment: Nothing concrete my approach would be following image search https://www.google.com/search?q=android+ril&tbm=isch

Comment: I appreciate it, thanks for the direction @Robert!

Comment: Modem/BP runs its own RTOS which is completely isolated from the main OS: Linux kernel and Android, and even bootloaders. Android talks to it roughly like talking to a remote host on network (consider NFS). The protocols used for communication are proprietary in 99% cases with a very small implementation (e.g. to access a shared memory area) in kernel (which has to be open source by law; GPL). Rest of the communication is handled by a vendor provided userspace daemon named RIL, as Robert said. You can reverse engineer it to get protocol details. Usually it's some extension to old AT commands.

Comment: @ThatCampbellKid Also be aware of the [Android Framework documentation on the Radio Interface Layer](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/ril)